# How to post with friendly_id in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

someone please can spare a hint on how to post with friendly_id?

After setup a simple commentary system that's ok, but with friednly_id i tried to post the comment rails spits out in the log

```
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 241ms
```

Seems due to not passing the properly id to the params

```
 Parameters: {"comment"=>{"commentable_id"=>"dde", "comment"=>"swsww", "commentable_type"=>"Post", "parent_id"=>"", "post_id"=>"dde"}, "post_id"=>"dde"}
```

More relevant info:

I've tried to use the post directly instead of resource but still the same

```
set_commentable
@commentable = if params[:comment_id]
                   Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id])
                 elsif params[:post_id]
                   Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
                 end
end
```

```
 def set_comment
    @comment = @commentable.comments.friendly.find(params[:id])
  rescue StandardError => e
    logger.error "#{e.class.name} : #{e.message}"
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build
    @comment.errors.add(:base, :recordnotfound, message: "That record doesn't exist. Maybe, it is already destroyed.")
  end

  def set_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]

    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.friendly.find(id)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id] || params[:id])
  end
```

The expected results will be to post the comment without any error

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MHd2.png)

Comment: It'd be better if you add more info about the stacktrace of your error.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, thank you i added a picture of the error

Comment: Try it in `rails console`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a single controller that handles multiple types of comment-able types you can check the params hash for what nested key is present:

```
class CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable

  private

  def set_commentable
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless commmentable_key
    @commentable = commentable_class.includes(:comments)
                                    .friendly.find(params[commmentable_key])
  end

  def commmentable_key
     @_commmentable_param ||= ["post_id", "video_id"].detect { |key| params[key].present? }
  end

  def commentable_class
    commmentable_key.chomp("_id").classify.constantize
  end
end
```

In this example we check for the keys "post_id" and "video_id". We then use a simple set of heuristics to guess that the class is Post or Video.

By extracting this into separate methods you can override the behaviour in subclasses.

Don't use `rescue StandardError => e` to catch the error that occurs if the record is not found. Its an anti-pattern known as [pokémon exception handling](http://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling). Only catch specific exceptions that you know how to handle.

```
 # DON'T DO THIS!
 rescue StandardError => e
    logger.error "#{e.class.name} : #{e.message}"
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build
    @comment.errors.add(:base, :recordnotfound, message: "That record doesn't exist. Maybe, it is already destroyed.")
  end
```

Instead use [`rescue_from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) to rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if you want to override the default 404 handler in rails. This will bail out of the action in your controller which is a good thing since it should not have to handle the scenario where the resource is not present.

```
class CommentsController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  def not_found
    render :not_found, status: :not_found
  end
end
```